# I need to update subsequent rows in a table based on date and column values without using a cursor in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This SQL shows a sample dataset I am working with

```
create table #tmp1
(
    Account varchar(18),
    CaseID varchar(18),
    DT datetime,
    Person varchar(100),
    Updated varchar(18)
)

insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12345', '1/1/13', 'me', 'Someone'
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12346', '2/1/13', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12347', '3/1/13', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12348', '4/1/13', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12349', '5/1/13', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12350', '6/1/13', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12351', '7/1/13', 'myself', 'Someone'
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12352', '8/1/13', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12353', '9/1/13', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12354', '10/1/13', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12355', '11/1/13', 'I', 'Someone'
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12356', '12/1/13', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12357', '1/1/14', 'Irene', 'Someone'
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12358', '2/1/14', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12359', '3/1/14', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12360', '4/1/14', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12361', '5/1/14', 'Olivia', 'Someone'
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12362', '6/1/14', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12363', '7/1/14', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12364', '8/1/14', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12365', '9/1/14', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12366', '10/1/14', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12367', '11/1/14', null, null
insert into #tmp1    Select 'MyAcccount',  '12368', '12/1/14', 'izzy', 'Someone'

select * from #tmp1
Order by Account, DT
```

What I need to do is update the `Person` column in each row that has a null value in the `Updated` column so that it matches the previous row regardless of the value that is in the `Person` column.

However I have been asked not to use a cursor. I have been trying to figure out a way to do this without a cursor but so far have not been very successful.

Has anyone been able to do something like this without a cursor?

Comment: What do you mean by `previous row`? Do you know that `SELECT * FROM #tmp1` does not guarantee the return order? unless you use an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: the Person column should be updated with a null? or the value in the updated field??

Comment: not clear.I think you should show output look like

Comment: the dates in the real data are sequential but there is no standard on how long in between dates in each row. I need the value of the person column on the record with a value in the updated column to roll over to all records until the next record with a value in the updated field. sorry i didn't explain it correctly the first time.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this, assuming your id's are unique and sequential without gaps:

```
UPDATE #tmp1
SET Person = (SELECT Person FROM #tmp T2 WHERE T1.CaseID = T2.CaseID + 1)
FROM #tmp T1
```

Comment: `T1.CaseID = T2.CaseID + 1` is just a sample. I doubt it is concrete in the real data.

Comment: It looks to be a primary key. If it's not, the primary key should be used. Alternatively if the dates are sequential, you can compare the dates by adding a month to the T2 date and comparing that with the T1 date.

Comment: I assume you mean an `Identity` column. Still, the identity column does not guarantee an incremental number. if 2 inserts are running in parallel transactions and the first one fail, the specific id will be lost and never used. That is a basic concept on how SQL Server guarantees identity on a multi-transaction environment.

Comment: I agree with your point, but the data that the OP posted was sequential without gaps. If this is not the case, it's still doable by assigning a new identity column in the temporary table when inserting in the desired order (this will not have gaps since it's a temp table and would not be inserted into via parallel transactions).

Comment: That is exactly what I meant by "is just a sample" :)

Comment: the dates in the real data are sequential but there is no standard on how long in between dates. I need the value of the person column on the record with a value in the updated column to roll over to all records until the next record with a value in the updated field. sorry i didn't explain it correctly the first time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE #TMP1
 SET person =<value> or (select updated from #tmp1) 
 WHERE updated = NULL
```

if you want any default value type in the value inside the the  field. if you want the corresponding value of updated column use the sub query.